# Android SharedPreferences How is it mean to be used?

Tags: android, preferences, default-value

I am struggling to restore the default values I specified in the preferences.xml, Here is my code:

```js
    Preference reset = findPreference(res.getString(R.string.DEFAULT_PREFS));
    reset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference p) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Preferences.this);
            sp.edit().clear().commit();
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(Preferences.this, R.layout.preferences, true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This code is my understanding of the android's developers reference for the function *setDefaultValues(context, resId, readAgain)*:

> **Parameters**
>
> > *context*    The context of the shared preferences.
> >     *resId*      The resource ID of the preference hierarchy XML file.
> >     *readAgain*  Whether to re-read the default values.
> >                 Note: this will NOT reset preferences back to their default values.
> >                 For that functionality, **use getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)
> >                 and clear it followed by a call to this method with 
> >                 this parameter set to true**.

Well, **it does not work**, the preferences values are the same after this code is executed.
Then I looked into the SharedPreferences variable sp, and it points to a system generated file in the path:
/data/data/<packagename>/shared_prefs/<packagename>_preferences.xml
which I can only assume is the same xml I provided when I created the activity.

```
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
```

Also inspecting the sp variable, the hash table has all the preferences, but there is no field for default value.

**EDIT:**
Before I am asked to, here is an excerpt from the preferences.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="5000"
    android:key="@string/MAX_MESSAGES"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:summary="@string/MAX_MESSAGES_desc"
    android:title="@string/MAX_MESSAGES_title" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="10"
    android:key="@string/VIEW_EDGE_ROWS"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:summary="@string/VIEW_EDGE_ROWS_desc"
    android:title="@string/VIEW_EDGE_ROWS_title" />

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:entries="@array/level_list"
    android:entryValues="@array/level_values"
    android:key="@string/INITIAL_ORG"
    android:summary="@string/INITIAL_ORG_desc"
    android:title="@string/INITIAL_ORG_title" />

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="2"
    android:entries="@array/view_list"
    android:entryValues="@array/view_values"
    android:key="@string/INITIAL_VIEW"
    android:summary="@string/INITIAL_VIEW_desc"
    android:title="@string/INITIAL_VIEW_title" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="@string/AUTOSCROLL"
    android:summary="@string/AUTOSCROLL_desc"
    android:title="@string/AUTOSCROLL_title" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="@string/SEND_THEN_EXIT"
    android:summary="@string/SEND_THEN_EXIT_desc"
    android:title="@string/SEND_THEN_EXIT_title" />

<Preference
    android:key="@string/DEFAULT_PREFS"
    android:summary="@string/DEFAULT_PREFS_desc"
    android:title="@string/DEFAULT_PREFS_title" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Can we get the full xml for preferences? The problem could be there and I will just speculate otherways

Comment: Added the full XML. So, in other words, you see the code and you think it should be working? (but it isn't)

Comment: I'm assuming this is a `PreferenceActivity`, right?

Comment: @Android, You use there the deprecated function `getSharedPreferences()` and manually set the value for each preference. That's not a good solution _for me_. If I cannot reset the values of all my prefs at once, from the defaults I have already defined in the XML I might as well turn the default values into resources and use them instead to reset manually.

Comment: I avoided the `PreferenceActivity` and just did it manually so my advice would be that. But to reset to default values, from the declared ones in xml, your code seems valid, if anything I'd try changing the `context` variables to one that ensures your using the activities context but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @thisMayhem, I did trace the SharedPreferences with the debugger and the file in its mFile field is the correct one, I think. Do you think that maybe the default values are restored somewhere, and I am missing some sort of invalidate() to see them updated on the activity?

Comment: Right, on your call to the setDefaultValues method you are passing what seems to be a layout instead of an xml file, is that the case?
`PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(CONTEXT, R.xml.preference, true);`

Comment: @thisMayhem, I am pretty sure it does not matter where in the res hierarchy it is placed. The XML source you saw, it's XML.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11332/discussion-between-ilomambo-and-thismayhem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution so far. After debugging into the Android source code I find out that `setDefaultValues()` is not reliable and does not work as intended (at least according to my expectations).
I restore the default values manually now. I have a map where I can fetch from the default values.

**Here is an interesting note**: Inspecting the Preference class shows it has a field called `mDefaultValue` which contains the default value for the preference. But this field can **only be set** by `setDefaultValue()` method, and there is no method to get it. It would have save me the need for a Map

This is the code I use now, tested and working:

```js
    Preference reset = findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.DEFAULT_PREFS));
    reset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference p) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Preferences.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.clear();
            // PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(Preferences.this, R.layout.preferences, false);
            for(int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
                restoreDefault(editor, getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
            }
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

```js
private void restoreDefault(Editor editor, Preference p) {
    if(p instanceof PreferenceCategory) {
        PreferenceCategory pCat = (PreferenceCategory) p;
        for(int i = 0; i < pCat.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            restoreDefault(editor, pCat.getPreference(i));
        }
    }
    if(p instanceof ListPreference) {
        editor.putString(p.getKey(), resMap.get(p.getKey())._default);
    }
    if(p instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        editor.putString(p.getKey(), resMap.get(p.getKey())._default);
    }
    if(p instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
        editor.putBoolean(p.getKey(), resMap.get(p.getKey())._default.equals("true"));
    }
}
```

Another note: `editor.commit()` updates the preferences file, but does not update the preferences screen. You have to update each preference by using the listener (`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`).